Two homomorphisms of Lie Group that have the same pushforward in the Lie Algebra
Let $G$ and $H$ be Lie Groups and $\Phi$,$\phi : G \rightarrow H$ be two homomorphisms of Lie groups, such that $\Phi_*:\mathfrak{g} \rightarrow \mathfrak{h}$ and $\phi_*:\mathfrak{g} \rightarrow \mathfrak{h}$ are the same. Then, if $G$ is connected, $\Phi = \phi$.
My approach to this problem was showing that taking $X$ to be a left-invariant vector field in $G$, then for every $g \in G$ one can get that $\Phi_{*,g} (X_g) \in T_{\phi(g)}H$. So, as this vector $\Phi_{*,g} (X_g)$ also belongs to $T_{\Phi(g)}H$, we conclude that $\Phi(g) = \phi(g)$. I think this last conclusion could be done in a more precise way by considering the natural projection $\pi: TH \rightarrow H$.
And my first statement is actually achieved by showing that $\Phi_{*,g} (X_g) = \phi_{*,g} (X_g)$, because homomorphisms kinda commute with left multiplication, so this is not hard to get.
But then, I am not convinced that my approach is correct, because I did not use the assumption that $G$ is connected, and perhaps $\Phi_{*,g} (X_g) = 0$ could be a problem.
Then I tried to use that every homomorphism of Lie Groups have constant rank, and I think my proof is valid when the rank is equal or greater than $1$, but when the rank is $0$ and probably would have to use the hypotesis that $G$ is connected.
Can somebody enlight me in this one, are there any mistakes in my argumentation?

In your argument, you only justify that $\Phi_(X)$ and $\phi_(X)$ are equal. You haven't showed that $\Phi=\phi$.

But applying $\pi$ in the equallity: $\Phi_{,g} (X_g) = \phi_{,g} (X_g)$ I get that $\Phi(g) = \phi(g)$, or not?Where $\pi: TH \rightarrow H$ is the natural projection.

What does $\Phi_{,g}$ mean? When you have a Lie group homomorphism $\Phi:G\to H$, you can differentiate it at the identity to get $\Phi_:\mathfrak{g}\to\mathfrak{h}$. This Lie algebra homomorphism does not depend of an element $g\in G$. So what can $\Phi_{*,g}$ mean?

$\Phi_{*,g}: T_gG \rightarrow T_{\Phi(g)}H$ is the pushforward of $\Phi$ at the point $g$. I'm using the same notation Loring Tu uses. The function is smooth everywhere, so I can consider this pushforward.

So it is the differential of $\Phi$ at $g$? In this case, one need to show that the differential of $\Phi$ and $\phi$ agree at each point $g\in G$, knowing it only at the identity. This requires $G$ to be connected.

Try using the exponential map $\exp: \mathfrak{g}\to G$, which is a local diffeomorphism. Also recall that for a connected topological group, any neighborhood of the identity generates it.
